# New Linklabel when button is pressed in webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, linklabel

I am making a web browser and I need to figure out something. When the user types into a text box and presses a button, it will make a new link label with that address that they typed into the text box. I've tried and looked everywhere but I can't find anything on how to do it.

Comment: I think we need a lot more information on this one. What platform are we dealing with here (ASP.Net, WinForms, etc.)? The answer to this question can vary greatly depending on this information.

Answer (score 0):

If using the built-in WebBrowser control, then you can do it all in js.  Of if you need interop with your c# code then you can get a reference to the dom document (`WebBrowser.Document`) and call standard dom methods.